# Windows 8 MsMpEng.exe high disk usage, uninstalled Defender, and now AvastSvc.exe

Tags: windows-8, windows-defender, avast, resource-usage

I recently disabled Windows Defender due to MsMpEng.exe randomly spiking up my computer's disk usage. I saw it from Task Manager->Details->I/O read and write bytes. The read bytes go as high as 12,000,000 bytes.

So I switched to Avast, which I thought would solve the problem. However, I encountered the same problem with my PC slowing down with no apparent reason. When I checked the Task Manager, it was AvastSvc.exe that's slowing it down. It also had read bytes that went more than 12,000,000 bytes. I checked my Avast and it's not even scanning or doing anything.

Is there a setting I'm supposed to change? This seems odd since I disabled automatic scanning in both Windows Defender (when it was still enabled) and Avast.

Comment: 12,000,000 bytes = 12 megabytes. That is not sounds so much demanding, can you post a pic just to be sure?